# jacoco.exec is not generating for karate test cases using maven surefire 2.19.1

Tags: java, maven, karate, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm using karate 0.9.6 version with springboot 2.3.x application, it is a maven multimodule project.

Using surefire I can run the testcases with mvn clean install with few -D args.
Also test class running as jUnit (using jUnit4) is working fine.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>                
    </configuration>               
</plugin>
```

But I'm facing difficulties to generate the jacoco coverage report. jacoco.exec is not generating.
I can see the surefire report for all and individual modules is generating successfully.
This is what it is saying.

```
argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\xxx\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.3\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.3-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\xxx\\git\\my-project\\my-controller-module\\target\\jacoco.exec

Reactor Summary for top-risk-inventory 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] my-inventory ................................. SUCCESS [  6.432 s]
[INFO] my-common ......................................... SUCCESS [ 13.602 s]
[INFO] my-domain ......................................... SUCCESS [ 17.378 s]
[INFO] my-service-layer .................................. SUCCESS [ 17.783 s]
[INFO] my-controller-module ..................................... SUCCESS [03:42 min]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:38 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-16T20:44:07+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

NB: I have gone through the @{argLine} related changes, not working any how for me. Another finding is surefire 2.2.1 is not compatible with few of my other dependency hence using 2.19.1

Thanks for any quick suggestion.

Comment: this is a tricky area, I don't have any answers but I will ask around

Comment: After few modification, finally able to generate the jacoco.exec
But now the issue is in jacoco report am getting coverage for all modules, but in jacoco.exec which publish the data to sonar is giving coverage for only one module.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can glean something from our implementation?

https://github.com/kirksl/karate-maven-gradle

Comment: Seems that https://github.com/kirksl/karate-maven-gradle is using JUnit 5, and in question there is "test class running as jUnit (using jUnit4) is working fine", so maybe problem of OP is similar to https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1048 - to execute JUnit 5 tests you need at least `maven-surefire-plugin` version `2.22.0`, while OP is using `2.19.1` and so JUnit 5 tests maybe not executed at all ;) Hope this helps.